# Отладка или поиск альтернатавы preg_replace

Tags: php

Узнал о функции `preg_replace`.

```
$zamena = "123";
$aaa = "12";
$aaa = preg_replace('/[^'.$zamena.']/', '', $aaa);
echo $aaa; // результат - "12;" должно быть - "12" // все сработало

$zamena = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ1234567890@#$%&()-=+?,.! ";
$aaa = "123 ^^ : ;";
$aaa = preg_replace('/[^'.$zamena.']/', '', $aaa);
echo $aaa; // результат - "123 ^^ : ;" должно быть - "123   " // как так?
```

Как видно из второго блока кода, функция почему-то работает не полностью. В описании этой функции не нашел ни слова про ";" и ":". Объясните, почему эти знаки функция не отсеивает? Как и не отсеивает многие другие.

P.S. Данная конструкция призвана из `$aaa` оставить знаки только те, которые в `$zamena`. В `$zamena` обычно русский и англиский алфавит + цифры + несколько символов, которые иногда стандартные, а иногда нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходимо экранировать спецсимволы при помощи [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg-quote)

```
$aaa = preg_replace('/[^'.preg_quote($zamena).']/', '', $aaa);
```

Либо вручную. Так же советую прочитать [документацию по регулярным выражениям](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) и [по конструкции `[]`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) в частности.

Comment: спасибо. и за ответ, и за то, в какую сторону дальше копоть 8-)